# How can I set default permissions on new nodes in Gentics Mesh?

Tags: gentics-mesh

I'd like anonymous users to have 'read published' permission to all newly created nodes under a specific node.

I can grant permission to a node after it's created, but is there a way to specify the permission when creating? Or is there a way to make new nodes inherit their parent node permissions by default?

I don't see the options in the node API docs, but curious if there was an undocumented feature, or maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

https://getmesh.io/docs/api/#project__nodes__post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All permissions (assigned role perms) of the parent node will automatically be inherited to the created children.

You can check the implementation here:
https://github.com/gentics/mesh/blob/dev/core/src/main/java/com/gentics/mesh/core/data/root/impl/NodeRootImpl.java#L258

Please file an issue with steps to reproduce if you have the impression that this is not working as expected.